# How to connect to an Amazon PostgreSQL database using SSL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, ssl

I'm trying to log into an Amazon PostgreSQL DBS using SSL.  I have all credentials but my `psql` version doesn't seem to support SSL.  I've tried searching Postgres docs but all I see is how it has native support.  Here's my command and output.  I'm running the `psql` command on a CentOS 6.5 box.

```
psql --host=XXXX.rds.XXXX.com  --sslmode=require --sslrootcert=rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem \
--port=XXXX --username=XXXXX --password --dbname=XXXX
```

Response:

```
psql: unrecognized option '--sslmode=require'
```

So my question is, how do I install a `psql` client that supports SSL.  I don't need the full blown DB support, just the connector, `psql`.

Thanks

I should add that I'm trying to follow these instructions.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL

Comment: The SSL support should be compiled in during the software installation, as [described here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/install-procedure.html). Apparently, it was not done.

Answer (score 3):

Many connection options aren't available as command line flags. That's one of them. Use a *connection string*, e.g.:

```
psql "host=XXXX.rds.XXXX.com sslmode=require sslrootcert=rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem port=XXXX user=XXXXX dbname=XXXX"
```

(Syntax corrected)